# firebase-tools: Unable to use GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or FIREBASE_TOKEN env vars to login

Tags: authentication, environment-variables, google-signin

I'm currently using the [firebase-tools](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools) to deploy using Ubuntu OS. I have been able to do it successfully once completed the login process using these commands based on the use of a refresh token:

```
sudo firebase logout
sudo firebase login:ci //generated token
export FIREBASE_TOKEN='{generatedToken}'
sudo firebase deploy --token=$FIREBASE_TOKEN
```

But I would like to use environment vars like is documented at the [github project](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools#authentication) without pass directly the token (--token=$FIREBASE_TOKEN):

> GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS - if this environment variable points to a service account key file, the Firebase CLI will authenticate as a service account.
> FIREBASE_TOKEN - you can explicitly use this environment variable to pass in a long-lived user token from firebase login: ci.

When I execute the following commands, **firebase-tools is not able to deploy because never did the login process**. Looks like is not recognising environment vars:

**a) Using FIREBASE_TOKEN environment var**

```
sudo firebase logout
export FIREBASE_TOKEN='a new generated token'
sudo firebase deploy
```

**b) Using GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment var**

```
sudo firebase logout
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='/path/service_account.json'
sudo firebase deploy
```

My credentials JSON file looks like this:

```
 {
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "project-name...",
  "private_key_id": "12f.....................",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvQIBADANB...........=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "firebase-adminsdk-...@domain.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "10651....",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/firebase-adminsdk-...w%40project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the real mistake was the use of the *sudo* command.
The environment variables never became available to the root user.
I have fixed the installation of firebase-tools for avoiding the use of root permissions and now it works perfectly.

Thanks a lot anyway!

Answer (score 0):

On *pakage.json* you need to add this on *serve*:

`export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=key.json &&`

Write it before at the beginning.

I upload an example.

[image]

I hope is usefull for you ;)

Comment: Hi @SeiyaJapon, I considered this solution as the good one at first due it resolved my issues with the root execution and the environment variables (sudo npm run <scriptId>). 
Anyway, finally, I get inspired by your serve script to prepare a default deploy script. 

Thanks a lot!